# Can you give a type argument to a TypeVar

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

Here is the situation I'm facing. I have class `A` and a generic type `B`. The type parameter of B bound to `A`.

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

AT = TypeVar("AT", bound="A")
BT = TypeVar("BT", bound="B")


class A:
    pass

class B(Generic[AT]):
    def __init__(self, a: AT):
        self._a = a

    def a(self) -> AT:
        return self._a
```

I also have a generic class `C` with type parameter bounded by `B`. I want this class to have a method `bar` that given an object of type `B` returns something of the same type as the type parameter of the B passed as argument. I tried

```
class C(Generic[BT[AT]]):
    def bar(self, b: BT) -> AT:
        return b.a()
```

However, type checking on the code below with mypy gives:

`Returning Any from function declared to return "AT"`

I also tried:

```
class C(Generic[BT]):
    def bar(self, b: BT[AT]) -> AT:
        return b.a()
```

but then I get the error

`Type variable "BT" used with arguments`

Is there a way to capture this idea with type annotation or a better way to structure the code to capture this constraint?

Any idea about that? Thank you!

Comment: why do you need `TypeVar`s in the first place?

Comment: Because in my context A, B and C are abstract class that can be implemented for various application

Comment: Usually a implementation of C works with a specific type B that work with a particular type A

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: No, I ended up having the class C be a generic in AT and BT